# Do you use Stack Overflow to choose between technologies or libraries?

Tags: discussion

While checking the different choices I had to build a project, I've used Stack Overflow to see which of my two choices were the most popular here, by checking the number of questions and subscribers of each tag.

It's the first time I've done this, I've used to look at the result counts returned by Google for this before, and I was curious to see if you're doing this too, and if you would have some advices to eventually improve it.

FYI, it was theses tags: [sylius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sylius) & [sonata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sonata)

Comment: (Might be too opinion based, could remove it if so)

Comment: No, and I would think the amount of questions asked on SO could also be a negative thing, at the end of the day, don't choose a library because of how many other people use it, choose it because it's best suited for the requirements and if they're similar to the point that they offer the same things, it doesn't matter :)

Comment: @George It's not my only criteria off course.

Comment: Of course not, that would be insulting to you to think you do that, but that is how this question is worded.

Comment: SO statistics can give you a pretty good indication how many programmers run into trouble using a library.  It doesn't tell you whether that's because the library is flawed or because it is popular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because I don't choose technologies or libraries based on their popularity. Although popularity *might* be on my list of considerations, it would be well toward the bottom, after other factors I consider much more significant, like:

- suitability to the task
- ease of use
- quality of documentation
- design and/or maintenance philosophy
- *et cetera*

The only real reason why popularity might matter is to the extent that it implies a technology/library is well-maintained. However, that's not necessarily true. Plenty of popular projects have been abandoned when their authors moved on to something else. This is one of the many reasons why open-source solutions are so popular, because then you can just take the code and maintain it yourself if you have to.

Comment: I should have added this to my question, it's not my only criteria. Thanks for answering, I'll accept it and call it a day.